# Rebinding infinitescroll plugin with new URL link on click

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

so i have a case like this, i want to rebind infinite scroll plugin on a clicked link and passing new URL to differ the content section that'll be generated later by it..

So far what i can do is triggering the infinite scroll and passing the section at the first clicked link.. after that when i clicked another link the URL link or the section won't be rebinded, i want it to be rebinded so it can differ the generated content.

moreless here's my code..

HTML

```
<li class="active"><a href="#" title="" data-filter=".w-all" class="w-filter">View All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="" data-filter=".w-branding" class="w-filter">Branding</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="" data-filter=".w-graphic" class="w-filter">Graphic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="" data-filter=".w-website" class="w-filter">Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="" data-filter=".w-photography" class="w-filter">Photography</a></li>
```

jQuery

```
$('a.w-filter').click(function(e){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    var section = selector.split('-');
    $('#page_nav a').attr('href', 'pager/1/'+section[1]);


    $(window).unbind('.infscr');

    $container.infinitescroll({  
        navSelector : '#page_nav',
        nextSelector : '#page_nav a',
        itemSelector : '.item',
        loading: {      
            finishedMsg: 'Hmm, I guess that\'s all we got.',    
            img: 'loading.gif',    
            msgText: '<em>Loading more projects.</em>'   
        },
        pathParse: function (path, currentPage) {
          var chunkedUrl = ['/pager/', '/'+section[1]];
          return chunkedUrl;
        }


    });

    $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');


    e.preventDefault();
});
```

can it be done?

Comment: `$(window).unbind('.infscr');` what is this code doing ?

Comment: that will unbind the infinitescroll plugin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infinite scroll plugin modify the path with custom query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453694/infinite-scroll-plugin-modify-the-path-with-custom-query)

Answer (score 1):

finally, i found the answer on this [Infinite scroll plugin modify the path with custom query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453694/infinite-scroll-plugin-modify-the-path-with-custom-query/18421656#18421656)

it has to modify the plugin source a lil bit, after that it works like a charm!

```
//line 67
$.infinitescroll.prototype = {
   //My custom parameters
    pageType: "&type=items",
    categoryParam: "&category=shoes",
    /*  
        ----------------------------
        Private methods
        ----------------------------
        */
```

thanks to the dude..

i found some issues again regarding this.. so when any section return 0 result the plugin will call 'end' function which destroys the instance, later then when i clicked any link the plugin wouldn't fire the event anymore. i've tried to rebind the instance using its 'bind' function but no luck, its 'retrieve' function only call finished message text the last state of the previous instance before it's destroyed. i still can't get it to rebind a new instance..

this is only alternative which i made, n also needs to modify the plugin source..
it won't call the 'end' function when a section return 0 result, but the plugin won't show finished text message anymore.

```
// near line 356, put comments tag before if(children.length === 0) to its closing brackets

// if it didn't return anything
/*if (children.length === 0) {
    return this._error('end');
}*/

// use a documentFragment because it works when content is going into a table or UL
frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
```

still hoping somebody could help to fix this the right way though..

Answer (score 0):

Try `$container.infinitescroll('destroy')`. If you're using the [2.0 version from github](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll), it should work (at least that's what I can tell by looking at the source code).

Comment: It's supposed to [destroy the current instance of the plugin](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js#l514).

Comment: @YogaFishguts I got the syntax wrong, check my updated answer

Comment: that's right, it is working the same like $(window).unbind('.infscr'); the matter is that how is the way or the syntax to rebind the plugin with new passed URL section[1] cause i think the $container.infinitescroll('retrieve'); is only continuing the first fired clicked infinitescroll event with its section[1] :/

Comment: i've found the solution :))

Comment: @YogaFishguts great, because I'm out of ideas! It would be great if you could post your solution as an answer, for future visitors who find this question.

Comment: ooh thanks for fixing my answer, well my hope is that the one who has similar trouble follow the link i've given cause the credits belong to the dude (:

Comment: @Yoga Yes, but if it's just a link, usually it's not considered a proper answer. I'll also mark your question as a duplicate of the other one, this should also make things easier to folks looking for the solution.